# Assert is not working

Tags: c++, assert

My assert is simply not working.

```
int tspace::Tpiz::set_pitPoz(int p)
{
    assert (0<=p<=11);
    pitPoz = p;
}
```

In main:

```
Tpiz piz;
piz.set_pitPoz(78);
cout << piz.get_pitPoz();
```

The output is:

```
78
- - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Process exited after 0.03378 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: `0<=p<=11` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Oh. What does my code mean?

Comment: If you want to ensure expressions are evaluated correctly then always start with them in an easy to test format.. So. `(0 <= p) and (p <= 11)` as the expression. There is no confusion to other people or the compiler exactly what you mean? You can always optimize it later if you think it is worthwhile?

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code and that works. Also, I think I figured out why 0<=p<=11 actually evaluates to true.0<=p evaluates to true, or 1, then the whole expression is true, because 1<=11 is true.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `0<=p<=11` probably evaluates `0<=p`, which yields a `bool`, but then it tries to involve this `bool` in a comparison against `11`, which is an integer, so it promotes the `bool` to `int`, (0 or 1,) and then checks to see whether this 0 or 1 is less than or equal to 11.  So, it will always succeed.

You might be able to avoid stupid accidents of that sort  by enabling more warnings, so that the compiler will warn you that you are most likely doing something wrong.  Try `-Wall`, or whatever it is that tells your compiler to enable all warnings.  You cannot be trying to write software without many, preferably most, warnings enabled.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into enabling all the warnings.

Comment: stupid? there's no need for name calling. In fact, given that x<=y<=z compiles yet does something completely unintuitive shows that this is more of a "subtle bug", not a "stupid accident".